# Add element in a list in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list and I would like to add an element inside only one of the list but it is added everywhere. You can find my code bellow

```
repartition_labels = [[]]*3
repartition_labels[2].append(2)
```

The result I have is

```
[[2], [2], [2]]
```

and I would like to have the result

```
[[], [], [2]]
```

I already tried to function insert and extend but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/8881141)

Comment: Use a list comprehension to construct the list. In this case it's only create 3 reference to the same list object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
repartition_labels = [[] for _ in range(0, 3)]
repartition_labels[2].append(2)
```

Output:

```
[[], [], [2]]
```

The reason your code is not working as expected, is because by `[[]] * 3` you're creating three references to the same list.

Answer (score 2):

With `repartition_labels = [[]]*3`, you are generating a list which contains 3 references to the same object.

When you change that object, all references will show the (same) updated object.

Comment: The duplicate flag exists for a reason on SO.